# Golang import grouping by package

Tags: go

I see that Go has goimports to help with import grouping, but I'm wondering if anyone has created a package to group imports in groupings by some pattern?

Go imports does this a little by enforcing at least two groupings stdlib and everything else; however, my company has a policy of grouping imports in 4 groups

```
import (
    stdlib

    current_project

    company

    all others 
)
```

is there a tool that can automatically do this?

Comment: `goimports` already sorts imports, and also maintains any groupings you make in the import block.

Comment: Regular old `go fmt` does the same thing.

Comment: I was hoping there was a tool that would make the groupings based on a regex or something.
goimports creates two groupings stdlib and everything else so it's close to what I want.

Comment: to be clear, add a blank line between groups you want to separate

Comment: Suggestion: Take a look at how goimports does it and then write your own tool for this to use in addition to goimports, and then edit save hooks to run both. https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/imports/sortimports.go

Comment: yep, that's the plan, was just checking to make sure there isn't already on before i spend the time on it.

Comment: For future reference this kind of question would be good to ask on the gophers slack channel or the go-nuts IRC channel.

Comment: Why don't you think this is good for stackoverflow?

Comment: Eh. It's ambiguous for sure. "hey is there a tool for this?" is called "tool shopping" on stack overflow and it's presented in contrast to problem solving which is the main focus of the site. But the boundaries are vague. I think more importantly on the irc and slack channels you're much more likely to get quicker and more informed responses.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The latest version of `goimports` support `-local` flag. Quoting [this commit message](https://github.com/golang/tools/commit/ed69e84b1518b5857a9f4e01d1f9cefdcc45246e):

For example, running `goimports -local example.com/` might produce

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "io"
    "strconv"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"

    "example.com/foo/bar"
    "example.com/foo/baz"
)
```

Comment: install:      go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
options:    goimports -h
example:   goimports -w -local "companyrepos/" .
where -w updates source file and . refers to current directory path

Answer (score 21):

If one is using GoLand, it's possible to adjust sorting in the settings:

[image]

Note “Group stdimports” and “Move all stdimports in a single group” checkboxes.

Comment: This works for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with Go as well

Comment: Nice answer, saved a lot of time during coding!

Answer (score 5):

I've also, tried to found the right answer on it until I solved the issue by myself... You could try this tool to sort Golang imports: https://github.com/incu6us/goimports-reviser.

It will sort and split your imports into 3-4 groups. Also, using `-local`-option you could set your company's libraries for sorting into separate group.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VScode, you can set the `local` flag. The settings.json looks like this:

```
"go.formatFlags": [
    "-local",
    "github.com/example/",
],
"go.useLanguageServer": false,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

The settings page looks like this:

[VS Code Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntt84.jpg)

You can set the `format on save` option to `true`. This will allow formatting of imports on every file save.